# Deploying docker-compose application on Azure Serverless

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-container-instances, taiga

I have the following application running on a Cloud VM. That is proving to be not economical.

[image]

As you can see this is a collection of different images. Is there a way to run this application on Azure serverless. I understand perhaps AKS(Kubernetes) might be one way to go. However, the YML config part might end up becoming too daunting for me. Kindly suggest if there are other approaches to this.

Comment: Azure web app for containers supports docker compose, however it has been in preview for a long time.

Comment: @YK1 Thank You for the pointer. I will explore that.

Comment: @TheFool I followed the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose and now I am stuck here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71725450/cannot-use-aci-volume-required-driver-is-azure-file .